# Use same database from different computers with Xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

I'm learning PHP and SQL using Xampp and I want to access my projects from two different computers. As I'm learning, I only work on localhost.
I got it working with PHP changing the document root variable in the httpd.conf file to my htdocs folder in OneDrive.
I've been trying to do something similar with the SQL database but everything I've tried ended up in errors in the phpMyAdmin site talking about extended functionalities not configured or SQL tables missing.
How can I access the same database, saved in a OneDrive folder, from anywhere?

Thanks!

Comment: SO are you planning to be using XAMPP on both PC's

Comment: Yes. Other option would be to find a free server hosting but for now I want to try the OneDrive aproach if possible.

Comment: The onedrive appraoch is the worst option. Dangerous even. Remember MySQL is a Database SERVER and can be accessed from anywhere with the right privilages and firewall settings so you could turn one PC into the server (for free). Alternatively, you allow access to your Apache through your firewall and as XAMPP has an FTP Server built in using a Source management tool like GIT and copying code up to the server woudl be a much better solution